# Unable to share variables between 2 flasks requests in a view function

Tags: python, flask, global

What I want  is to share a variable between 2 flask requests!
The variable is a large pandas dataframe.

I have read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46023219/4683950)  that i need to use g from [flask global](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g) !
basically, I have 2  views function like this :

```
from flask import g
@home.route('/save', methods=['GET'])
def save_ressource():
    an_object = {'key': 'value'}
    setattr(g, 'an_object', an_object)
    return 'sucees'
@home.route('/read', methods=['GET'])
def read_ressource():
    an_object = getattr(g, 'an_object', None)
    if an_object:
        return 'sucess'
    else:
        return 'failure'
```

***but this always return failure ie : None***

and when i read in the documentation here it's said that :

> Starting with Flask 0.10 this is stored on **the application context** and
> no longer on the request context which means **it becomes available if
> only the application context is bound** and not yet a request.

My question is how to solve this problem?

As said in the docs how can I bound application context?

Should I use sessions instead?

Any helps will be appreciate

Comment: the application should only work in localhost !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The linked answer appears to be completely wrong. The `g` object is for storing global data from one function to another *within the same request*, and is not at all for sharing data between requests.

For that you need [sessions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions):

```
from flask import Flask, session

@home.route('/save', methods=['GET'])
def save_ressource():
    an_object = {'key': 'value'}
    session['an_object'] = an_object
    return 'sucees'

@home.route('/read', methods=['GET'])
def read_ressource():
    an_object = session.get('an_object')
    if an_object:
        return 'sucess'
    else:
        return 'failure'
```

Comment: okay, Thanks for the quick answer sir, But can this works if I want to save a  large object?? ex a Dataframe??

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: the reason is that a dataframe is not JSON serializable.

Comment: But you can create a [custom encoder](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/) to handle any object and serialize it.

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi you can use `df.to_dict()` and `df.to_json()` methods to serialize your dataframe to use across sessions.